# Verb-てあった vs verb-てあります

Tags: suffixes

Does verb-てあった　mean the same thing as verb-てあります?

Comment: You mean てあった(the past tense/plain form) and てありました (the past tense/polite form), or てある(the present tense/plain form) and てあります(the present tense/polite form)？

Comment: No they do not. The former is plain past form. The latter is polite non-past form. I don't know why you are comparing particularly those two forms. It just looks as if you randomly choose two forms.

Comment: Why be so harsh on someone asking a simple question? Yes, they have mixed up two unrelated verb forms... *that's why they are asking*! Everyone has to start somewhere. Lighten up.

Comment: Can you give us examples? Then the answer will be more concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question simply, the two forms you are asking about do not mean the same thing.

You've actually got two differences at work here.

One difference is the politeness level. ~てあった, is the plain form. ~てあります is the polite form.

The other difference is the tense. ~てあった, is the past tense. ~てあります is the present tense.

I hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: OK, so ~てあった is the plain form of ~てありました.  Thanks!